# ggplot2 0.9.1: Logarithmic y-axis scale with barchart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to convert the y-axis of a bar-chart to a logarithmic scale (I.e. logarithmic distance between each ticks).

Some dummy data:

```
DF <- data.frame(num=c(1,2,3),label=c("a","b","c"))
```

I've tried the following examples:

```
p <- ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=label,y=num)) + geom_bar() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10',
                     breaks=trans_breaks("log10",function(x) 10^x),
                     labels=trans_format("log10",math_format(10^.x)))
```

This only log transforms labels, but not ticks:

```
p <- ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=label,y=num)) + geom_bar() + coord_trans(y="log10")
```

This doesn't plot anything at all:

```
p <- ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=label,y=num),y="log")
```

No luck either

I have also read [the 0.9 transition guide](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf)  , but that does not seem to work either.

## EDIT:

I forgot to include one example I tried:

p <- ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=label,y=num)) + geom_bar() + scale_y_log10()

Which produces the following warning:

Warning message:
In pretty(trans(x), n, ...) : NaNs produced

Comment: Using a log-scale for a bar chart is a bad idea, since bar measure the distance from zero.  Use a dot plot instead.  http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/b-eye/dot_plots.pdf

Comment: I tried using a dot plot, and it worked with the dummy data. But when I switched to the actual data, which ranges from 20865 to 127135230, the y-axis label only displays 10^5

Comment: Did you try a dot plot with a logarithmic y scale?  It should give you more axis label with that sort of data range.  If not, you can manually specify the `labels` arg in `scale_y_log10`.

Answer (score 9):

if you want to do a log 10 scale use

```
p + scale_y_log10()
```

Comment: works for me...in fact I just copied the code you put in your edit...perhaps there is something wrong with the data you are using..., i.e. you cant have negative values if trying to use a log scale?

Comment: I don't understand that. I tried copying my own example with dummy data, and still not working. What version of ggplot2 are you using? The actual data is fine as well, it's just that it ranges from 20865 to 127135230

Comment: ggplot2_0.9.1 according to my `sessionInfo()`. You sure you don't have any NAs in there?

Comment: I tried rebuilding it, and the dummy example is working now. There's no NAs in my actual data. str(df) reports all integers, and summary(df) doesn't report any NAs

Comment: Possibly check that you are using `geom_bar(stat='identity')`. You forgot the `stat='identity'` in the code above. `p <- ggplot(data=DF,aes(x=label,y=num)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_y_log10()`