# Different Starting Point (not 0)  in barplot Y-Axis?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple bar graph including two bars showing the average math scores of two groups of students. The averages are 363.2 and 377.4. creating bar graph is simple. What I'd like to do is to have my y-axis starts from 340 rather than 0. I do know how to change the limits of y-axis, but the issue is when I change the limit of y-axis to c(340, 380), R still draws the whole bar which most of it is below the x-axis!

Here is my code:

```
barplot(c(363.2, 377.4), beside = T, ylim = c(340,380), col = c("orange", "blue"))
```

I've also attached my plot:

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `xpd=FALSE` and re-adding the horizontal axis works, sort of:

```
b <- barplot(c(363.2, 377.4), beside = TRUE, 
   ylim = c(340,380), col = c("orange", "blue"),xpd=FALSE)
axis(side=1,at=b,labels=c("group 1", "group 2"))
box(bty="l")
```

I claim (I can't point you to a definitive reference, although [Googling "bar plot zero axis"](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/10/21/reader-poll-axis-scaling-bar-charts/) seems to come up with useful stuff; perhaps others will chime in) that it is **bad practice** to draw bar graphs where the vertical axis does not include zero: the argument is that the viewer will assume that bar graphs are anchored to the origin (this argument is more commonly made when explaining why R doesn't make it easy to use a logarithmic axis for barplots: see [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646655/ggplot2-0-9-1-logarithmic-y-axis-scale-with-barchart), for example).  Those who feel this way would say you should use points to indicate the value instead; in this case the implicit assumption of zero-anchoring does not hold as strongly.

In other words, "here's how you can do this -- but you shouldn't" ...

Comment: +1 You're absolutely right Ben - some people see this as 'deceiving' the person looking at the plot, and it should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Whether you "have to" start your y-axis at 0 is controversial. For discussion, see [How to determine whether or not the y-axis of a graph should start at zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/184525/) on [stats.SE].

Comment: I agree that there is a lot of nuance involved in deciding on a baseline value for y-axes. In the story referenced in the answer to that question, I would argue that one should use points with a non-zero anchor, rather than bars with a zero anchor. Bars with a non-zero anchor would probably be better than bars with a zero anchor, but the only compelling argument I can see for zero-anchored bars is cultural ("my audience expects it/my boss insists on it")

Answer (score 5):

The following can be seen if you look at `?barplot`:

"xpd:    logical. Should bars be allowed to go outside region?"

You just need to include `xpd=FALSE` in your parameters for the barplot.