# gg plot error bars positioning

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make the error bars above each bar plot, but I have the bar plots in three groups, and 6 bar plots and it's positioning the error bars with respect to each group, but I want the positioning if each error bar above each bar. Here's what my data looks like:

NewData

```
Group Session HeartRate StdError  n        sd

1 Novices     one  71.89276 1.821146 29  9.807170
2 Experts     one  66.40705 1.923901 26  9.810008
3 Novices     two  71.38609 1.571261 29  8.011889
4 Experts     two  67.79910 1.788151 26  9.117818
5 Novices   three  71.79759 1.941730 29 10.456534
6 Experts   three  67.04564 1.938620 26  9.885061
```

And here is my code:

```
plot_2 = ggplot(NewData, aes(x=Session, y=HeartRate, fill=Group)) +
     theme_bw() +
     geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity")+
     scale_x_discrete(limits=c("one","two","three")) +
     coord_cartesian(ylim = c(50, 80)) +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate-StdError,ymax=HeartRate+StdError),position="dodge",width=.25)
```

Here's the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSix2.png

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

OK-- I found a solution, not really sure how or why it works, but here's my new code:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
plot_2 = ggplot(NewData, aes(x=Session, y=HeartRate, fill=Group)) +
         geom_bar(position=dodge)+
         scale_x_discrete(limits=c("one","two","three")) +
         coord_cartesian(ylim = c(50, 80)) +
         geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate-StdError,ymax=HeartRate+StdError),position=dodge,width=.25)
```

And here's the desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXy5U.png

Comment: I understand you wish to have a y-axis that start at 50, but you may read [Ben Bolker's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695502/different-starting-point-not-0-in-barplot-y-axis/11695689#11695689) for argument against not having an axis that includes zero. I don't think you need `scale_x_discrete` here.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to tell what it is you want to see as output, but from what I gather, perhaps this will do what you want?

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate,ymax=HeartRate+StdError*2),position="dodge",width=.25)
```

If you want to move the error bar along the x-axis, we need to modify position=dodge. I don't see much documentation but you might try something like...

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate-StdError,ymax=HeartRate+StdError),position=group-10,width=.25)
```

or

```
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate-StdError,ymax=HeartRate+StdError),position=Session-10,width=.25)
```

Or (most likely?) this:

```
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HeartRate-StdError,ymax=HeartRate+StdError),position=x-10,width=.25)
```

Comment: @cseb Oh okay, in that case, did my modification give you what you were looking for?

Comment: No, it just shifted the error bar up on the yaxis, I'm wondering how to shift it on the xaxis to make it in the center of each bar plot.

Comment: @cesb Try the new suggestions, I think "x-10" / "x+10" etc. has a good chance.

Comment: Scott -- none of these really work. The interpreter says: Error in .$position$adjust : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @cseb Well then I dunno. Hopefully someone else can answer you.